# How to unescape systemd names?

Tags: python

Systemd documents its main rule for escaping non-alphanumerical characters in unit names this way:

> any "/" character is replaced by "-", and all other characters which are not ASCII alphanumerics or "_" are replaced by C-style "\x2d" escapes.

and there is also an example of unescaping:

```
$ systemd-escape -u 'Hall\xc3\xb6chen\x2c\x20Meister'
Hallöchen, Meister
```

(More info in the docs [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) and [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-escape.html))

Let's ignore the trivial replacement `"/"` -> `"-"`. I'm trying to unescape systemd names in Python (without 3rd party libraries). Many solutions I tried did not work, they converted the two bytes UTF-8 `"ö"` to two characters.

Finally this seems to produce the correct answer:

```
>>> esc=r'Hall\xc3\xb6chen\x2c\x20Meister'
>>> esc.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'Hallöchen, Meister'
```

As you see it goes: `str -> bytes -> str -> bytes -> str`. Could it be simplified somehow?

Comment: Aside from hacks with `ast.literal_eval` or `ftfy`, your solution is pretty much the shortest one, although I would replace the first instance of `'latin-1' with 'ascii', for correctness' sake.

Comment: I dont think theres anything too wrong with your solution, when encapsulated in a function it should perform adequately

Answer (score 2):

Instead of raw string`esc = r'...'` use bytes string `esc = b'...'` like in python3 example:

```py
>>> esc = b'Hall\xc3\xb6chen\x2c\x20Meister'
>>> esc.decode('utf-8')
'Hallöchen, Meister'
```

Comment: That won't work if they literally get the characters ``\``, `x`, `c`, and `3`.

Comment: The strings to unescape are program inputs. If I could define them in my program, I would directly enter them in the unescaped form.

Comment: In this case, the solution of 3rd part libraries which mention  L3viathan is the way to go.